# Checking for .txt tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to do a check for .txt. When trying to add multifile (multiple = True), it gives an error that the file is not .txt. How can this problem be solved. Thank you in advance

```
@staticmethod
# file input method
def open_file():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True)
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(str(file))

    if extension != '.txt':
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "You did not select a .txt file")
```

Comment: You can use ```else``` if the file isn't txt

Comment: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: Oh, I forgot it's a tuple. You will need to manually check each file. Use a ```for``` loop for that. like: ```for i in file:``` Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the variable `file` returns a tuple, we need to use a `for` loop. Then, you can use `.endswith()`. Example:

```
for i in file:
    if i.endswith(".txt"):
        print(True)
    else:
       print(False)
```

If you want to show the error only one time, you can add an extra variable there.

```
tm = 0
for i in file:
    if i.endswith(".txt"):
        pass
    else:
        if tm == 0:
            print(False)
            tm = 1
```

Comment: if `file` is a string then simply do `if file.endswith('.txt'):`, no? otherwise it won't work or correct that `file` is a tuple or sth

Comment: @Matiiss Yes, I know it can be used for a string only. I realized that after posting, so I edited it. Now it uses a ```for``` loop.